# create a web application from a node.js package

Tags: node.js

I am absolute beginner in node.js . I use this package: https://npmjs.org/package/node-clips. The package allows a user to interact with an expert system written in CLIPS through the console. What i want is to make a web app with this. That the client can send input to the server through the browser console and accept messages. Is there a package/way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be taking commands in the form of http requests, I recommend using Express.js. Its great for web servers and apis.

It allows you to define routes and bind them to functions through asynchronous callbacks.

```
app.get('/user/:userId',function(request,response) {
    console.log("I'm getting a request for user",request.param('userId'));
    response.send('hello world');
});
```

Now, if you're thinking you want to do interactions from *chrome's* web console (which I think you are maybe saying?) you will have to use ajax or write some sort of request wrapper on the client side. This client side wrapper would make ajax calls to this node route.